# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS new installation: Setting window not visible

Tags: unity, window

After complete install of Ubuntu 20.04, the settings window is not visible. The settings app does launch and it's icon is displayed in the launch bar, also if I right-click on it and choose 'All Winows' there is a preview image of the settings  menu, but the window is not displayed on the desktop. Shift-win-left arrow does not help.

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Did you get any workaround for this issue? I tried reinstalling the gnome-control-center but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem due to the upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.40. I had a `gnome-tweaks` on my machine before the upgrade. I removed it, and I installed `gnome-control-center`. Something like the following could work:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-tweaks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I connected my PC to a TV via HDMI and the "settings app" window appeared. "Windows mode" was in "join screens"; I changed it to "single screen", clicked on "apply" (green button in the upper right corner of the window), closed the "settings app" window and disconnected the HDMI cable from the PC. With this the problem was solved; now whenever I start "settings app" its window becomes visible.